# Can I download free games with an expired PlayStation Plus subscription?

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

I had a PlayStation Plus subscription but it expired. Can you not still download the free games you have if you do it on a console that you had your account set to primary?

Answer (score 3):

When your subscription lapses so does your access to the games (except those actually bought for at least some money). You get access back by subscribing again.