# If my Playstation Plus account expires, will I lose any of my data?

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

I want to renew my Playstation Plus account on the day it expires. Will I lose any data? Or should I always renew it before it expires?

Answer (score 3):

You can renew your Playstation Plus subscription whenever you want.

When you buy the subscriptions from the store while you still have time left it adds onto what you currently have. ie

- you have 3 months left before your subscription expires
- you buy another 12 months from the store
- your subscription now ends in 3 + 12 = 15 months

Also when you first subscribe [your subscription auto-renews](https://www.playstation.com/en-au/explore/playstation-plus/how-to-renew/) (unless you turned it off)

> When you joined PS Plus, we switched the auto-renew feature on. If you switched it off, you’ll need to enable it again by following the steps below. Then, by adding up to date card details and turning on the auto-funding feature, you can make sure your PS Plus membership automatically renews.

if however you allow your subscription to expire you can re-enable it to gain access to the stuff you had before as indicated in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/316547/30879)

> When your subscription lapses so does your access to the [free] games (except those actually bought for at least some money). You get access back by subscribing again.

while it talks about just the free games i would assume the same with the cloud saves where if your subscription expired you loose access to them but they wont be deleted/lost

So there is really no "better" option as to when you renew your subscription wether it's "banking" more time, letting the Auto-renew charge your card or by rebuying the subscription after letting it expire